# App crashes on a certain iPhone model (iPhone5 A1429)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, crash

There is an iPhone app called WiseCall which I have uploaded on the App Store. This works as accordingly, when you download the app and log in to your account in it on iPhone models like iPhone4s (A1387) and iPhone5 (A1457) and iOS version 9.2.

But for some reasons when a user with the iPhone5 model (A1429) and iOS 9.2 download the app and tries to log in to his/her accounts it always crashes for that particular user. Just because it occurred some kind of fatal error message with static string in the library file "libSwiftCore.dylib" when trying to load a UITabBarController that contains a UIViewController, as seen in the crash report below.

[image: Crash report in Xcode]

How come this error can occur in iPhone5 (A1429) and not with iPhone5 (A1457) or iPhone4s (A1387)? I have used this app on my iPhone4s and it worked perfectly fine for me to log in to the system, same thing for the other user who has the A1457 model. Is it something wrong with that users iPhone or could it be something else?

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to do anything other than guess.

Comment: How many cases of your app failing on an A1429 do you have? Just this one user, or are you sure it always crashes on such devices?

Comment: Or perhaps the iPhone is jailbroke.  Jailbreaked? Jailbroken? One of those.